# Problems with tmux, mutt, and terminal colors

Tags: linux, terminal, tmux, mutt

If I start `mutt` in a `tmux` session like this:

```
$ tmux new-session -s mutt mutt
```

Mutt complains:

```
Error in /home/lars/.mutt/colors, line 20: 230: color not supported by term
Error in /home/lars/.mutt/colors, line 26: 244: color not supported by term
```

But if I start `tmux` like this, without a command:

```
$ tmux new-session -s mutt
```

And then inside the `tmux` session start `mutt`:

```
$ exec mutt
```

It works without a problem.  In both cases, `TERM` inside the `tmux` session is set to `screen-256color`.  I don't see any functional difference between these two cases, so I'm confused. For what it's worth, the `-2` option to tmux ("Force tmux to assume the terminal supports 256 colours") doesn't seem to have any effect on this behavior.

Has anyone seen this behavior?  Do you know what causes it, and how to resolve it?

Comment: Is your mutt compiled with slang or ncurses? Provide `mutt -v` output please.

Answer (score 0):

`tmux new-session -s mutt` followed by `echo $TERM` results in `xterm-256color`

however,

```
tmux new-session -s mutt 'echo $TERM && sleep 10'
```

yields `screen`. To get around this, try:

```
tmux new-session -s mutt 'TERM=xterm-256color; echo $TERM && sleep 10'
```

to see the correct setting, and to make mutt work:

```
tmux new-session -s mutt 'TERM=xterm-256color mutt'
```